# How to pass values to catch block from outside try/catch (Without Using Global Variables)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, try-catch, task-parallel-library

Have a look at the following code:

```
try
{
    Parallel.Foreach(...)//50 Thread For Each Time
    {
        string str = MyMethod();
    }
}
catch
{

}
public string MyMethod()
{
     CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

     // Some code that throws an exception.
}
```

How can I pass `cookieJar` to the catch block?

**Note:**
For some reason I can't use global variables. I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` in `try` And I can't control global variables inside `MyMethod` because of parallel changes.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create 50 different `CookieContainer` instances? Which one do you want to use if an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could catch the exception in `MyMethod` and rethrow a new exception that will hold the `CookieContainer` object:

```
try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(...)
    {
        string str = MyMethod();
    }
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // This is where you can choose which exceptions to handle.
    foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions.OfType<MyCookieException>())
    {
        CookieContainer c = ex.CookieContainer;

        // Do stuff with CookieContainer.
    }
}

public string MyMethod()
{
     CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
     try
     {
         // Some code that throws an exception
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new MyCookieException(ex, cookieJar);
     }
}
```

Comment: `Parallel.Foreach` throws an `AggregateException` if any threads throw an exception so your catch block will never be executed.

Comment: @Lee Thanks, I've edited my answer, I believe this should work.

Comment: Won't `AggregateException` hold `MyCookieException` as inner exception? (I'm still working with .NET 3.5)

Comment: @Adi Lester thanks for the answer. but what is this -> foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions.OfType<MyCookieException>()), i want only one cookiejar each time.

Comment: As @Lee mentioned, `Parallel.ForEach` will throw an `AggregateException` that contains all the exceptions thrown inside of it. When you catch it, you can iterate over all the exceptions that were thrown in `MyMethod`. Inside the `foreach` loop you will be able to access all those exceptions, one at a time.